What could block carrierwave uploading to rails7 app on 'railsplayground' using passenger?
*** Updated and Closed ***
Turns out that I had to change the relative path in the uploader to the fully declared path for the server in which my app is running.  Who would have thought?
***  closed  ***
Trying to do the most simple of carrierwave operations -- basic loading to public/uploads....
Gemfile:   gem 'carrierwave', "~> 3.0.7"
Controller: require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
Model: mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
rails g uploader Image
to generate ImageUploader.rb with no changes.
sqlite3 db: table has row for image:string
My app works find on my development system in both dev and production (tested in production using ngrok).  But on the 'railsplayground' service, which my app 'sees' and displays the images loaded into the public/uploades path when the app was compressed (tar) and moved, the app 'hangs' trying to upload.
'Railsplayground', at the base level I am purchasing, does not give me access to the production log, and does not run the development environment, so I can not get any indicator of what is causing the 'hang'.  (progress bar goes to ~10% and freezes)
Any suggestions on how to trouble shoot?

Appears I have to use the fully formed pathname in the 'uploader.rb' file and carrierwave and the app are no longer fighting!

I found that the path name has to be fully qualified and that the partial path in the base uploader file will not work (at least on this implementation on Rails PlayGround).
